# How to separate this PHP and HTML source

Tags: php, html

I have a `change_username.php` which makes it possible for users to change their username. If they changed their username a page like "Your new username ist xxx" or "xxx is already used" will be displayed.

I don't want to use an `echo` and put all the HTML stuff in there.

My first idea would be to create another 2 PHP's which then get the username from the `change_username.php` and display a proper result with HTML.

Are there any alternatives / better ways to do that? Creating files for every result sucks as much as putting the HTML data in an `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you want to include a page with in your PHP: try using this as reference http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

You can include the page using

```
include 'filename';
```

or

```
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a little bit differently, I think the problem is with managing the code where large page is getting messy. What I do in these cases I just use functions with parameters. So I create a lib.php file, where I store function with HTML blocks of code being echoed. Then when I need I call these functions in the necessary files, just requiring lib.php at the top of my page.